# Creating a (grouped) summary of linear or nonlinear models to join to a table and predict values

Tags: r, lm

I have a table with three columns: x and y, and id. I would like to create a linear model for each id.

```
   id  x  y
1   a  1  2
2   b  5 10
3   a  8 16
4   b  1  2
5   a  6 12
6   c  9 18
7   a  2  4
8   a  9 18
9   b  1  2
10  b  6 12
11  b 10 20
12  c 12 24
13  c  2  4
14  c  4  8
15  c  5 10
```

I can do this with either split/apply or using nlme's `lmList` function. How exactly would I create a summary table with the id, and store its respective linear model in a small summary table?
Also, how would I join the summary table back to the above data frame (or another data frame with an ID column and an x column)? Then, would it also be possible to use the joined linear models and predict the outcome using the respective x value in a given row

```
# Representation of what it would look like to join and predict the linear model

   id  x  lm
1   a  1  <first lm here>
2   b  5 <second lm here>
```

Would it be possible to predict y using the respective lm for a given x value, using the example above? Can this also be extended to other models like `knn3` and `loess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this approach. As long as you know the order of your ids, you define them in a tibble and store their respective linear models in a list column.

*Further explanation*: The `map` command that defines `summarydata$lm` splits `df1` into three separate dataframes based on the value of `id`, and then fits a linear model to each of these dataframes. The resultant model object is then stored in `summarydata$lm`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducing your data
df1 <- tibble(
  id = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
  x = c(1, 5, 8, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 1, 6, 10, 12, 2, 4, 5),
  y = c(2, 20, 26, 2, 12, 18, 4, 18, 2, 12, 20, 24, 4, 8, 10)
)

summarydata <- tibble(
  id = c("a", "b", "c"),
  x = c(1, 5, 7),
  lm = map(group_split(df1, id), ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .))
)
```

Then, to get the predictions from each linear model, we can use another map command inside mutate. This takes each linear model and each value of `x` from `summarydata`, and computes a predicted value of y using `predict`.

```
summarydata %>%
  mutate(
    prediction = map2_dbl(lm, x, ~ predict(.x, newdata = tibble(x = .y)))
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  id        x lm     prediction
  <chr> <dbl> <list>      <dbl>
1 a         1 <lm>         1.69
2 b         5 <lm>        12.0 
3 c         7 <lm>        14
```

Comment: Thanks! What does this do? `map(group_split(df1, id), ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .))`, as well as this:  `map2_dbl(summarydata$lm, summarydata$x, ~ predict(.x, newdata = tibble(x = .y)))`

Comment: @AntPalmer You're welcome! I've updated my answer with a bit more explanation about what those commands do. If you haven't encountered `map` functions before, they're a way of applying another function across a list or vector of input values. [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html) has a good chapter on this.